# Changing Table column and row span at runtime

Tags: jquery, html

Having a table that looks like this:

```
[Cell][Cell][Cell][Cell]
[Cell][Cell][Cell][Cell]
[Cell][Cell][Cell][Cell]
```

I would like to change its content at runtime to look like this:

```
[Cell][Cell][  ONE ]
[Cell][Cell][  BIG  ]
[Cell][Cell][  CELL ]
```

And then have an ability to revert it back to original state.

Based on your experience what is the best approach to achieve such a behavior?

UPDATED:
Here is what i would like to do `dynamically` without creating a new table:
http://jsfiddle.net/pyuQD/3/

Comment: Do you have some actual HTML to share? Perhaps you could explain your use-case, so that we can offer actual advice, rather than guessing your intent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my approach.
You simply add one more cell to the first row and hide it. You also specify `rowspan` and `colspan` attributes for it. Then you can use jQuery to toggle the `td`s and the `.one-big-cell`.
By adding additional `td` we, of course, waste DOM but this way it's easier to preserve to whole content of all `td`s.

**HTML**:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>CELL</td>
        <td>CELL</td>
        <td>CELL</td>
        <td>CELL</td>
        <td class="one-big-cell" colspan="2" rowspan="3">ONE BIG CELL</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>CELL</td>
        <td>CELL</td>
        <td>CELL</td>
        <td>CELL</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>CELL</td>
        <td>CELL</td>
        <td>CELL</td>
        <td>CELL</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**:

```css
.one-big-cell {
    display: none;
}
```

**jQuery**:

```
$bigCell = $('table .one-big-cell');
$('#switch').on('click', function() {
    if ($bigCell.is(':visible')) {
        $('table td:not(:visible)').show();
    } else {
        $('table td:nth-child(2), table td:nth-child(3)').not('.one-big-cell').hide();
    }
    $bigCell.toggle();
});
```

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/JnxL4/

Answer (score 0):

You could have a hidden cell with colspan as much as you want and keep it as a hidden cell. You can write a function to show that hidden cell and you can hide the cells that you want to hide.

Methods to show/hide big/small cells could look like below.

```
    
    $("#merge").click(function() {
        $("table tr td.bigcell").show().prev().hide().prev().hide();
    });
    $("#revert").click(function() {
        $("table tr td.bigcell").hide().prev().show().prev().show();
    });
```

Please have a look at the below fiddle for working version of the above said approach
[enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/qQ4Ky/)